# Subclassing foreign Service does not work

Tags: typo3, extbase, subclassing, typo3-7.6.x

I'm trying to subclassing the FileCollectionService class from third party extension. But it takes not place.

ext_typoscript_setup.txt:

```
config.tx_extbase{
persistence{
    classes{
        SKYFILLERS\SfFilecollectionGallery\Service\FileCollectionService {
            subclasses {
                TxFileCollectionService = FalkRoeder\MyExt\Service\FileCollectionService
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

my FileCollectionService.php put in Classes/Service

```
<?php
namespace FalkRoeder\MyExt\Service;

/**
 * FileCollectionService
 */
class FileCollectionService extends \SKYFILLERS\SfFilecollectionGallery\Service\FileCollectionService {

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function methodToOverwrite() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get it work, I needed to add the following code to ext_typoscript_setup.txt:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    objects {
        SKYFILLERS\SfFilecollectionGallery\Service\FileCollectionService.className = FalkRoeder\MyExt\Service\FileCollectionService
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to something Like this.

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            SKYFILLERS\\SfFilecollectionGallery\\Service\\FileCollectionService {
                subclasses {
                    TxFileCollectionService = VendorName\ExtensionKey\Classes\Utility\FileCollectionService

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```